# Setting ContentType = "image/tiff" and sending an image is not working in IE

Tags: asp.net

I need to send an image (as a downloadable file) from an ASP web page.  It is working correctly in every browser except for IE (all versions).

Here is the server side code:

```
bool export = Request.QueryString["Export"] != null;
if (export)
{
    byte[] allBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\MyImage.tif");
    Response.ContentType = "image/tiff";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"MyImage.tif\"");
    Response.OutputStream.Write(allBytes, 0, allBytes.Length);
    Response.OutputStream.Flush();
    Response.End();
    return;
}
```

And here is the JavaScript:

```
$('#ExportFrame').attr('src', 'Default.aspx?Export=true'); // ExportFrame is an iframe
```

In IE, I keep getting an error saying "Internet Explorer cannot download Default.aspx from localhost".  I thought it might be an issue with loading it in an iframe element, but redirecting to the URL is not working either.  The really odd thing is that going to the URL (/Default.aspx?Export=true) does not work the first time, but works every time after that.  Again, this works in every browser I've tried except IE.

Any ideas?

Update:
The aspx page has the following code to keep the page from getting cached:

```
// Never cache this page
Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
Response.Expires = -1;
```

Removing the first 2 lines and leaving only `Response.Expires = -1` resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The aspx page had the following code to keep the page from getting cached:

```
// Never cache this page
Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
Response.Expires = -1;
```

Removing the first 2 lines and leaving only `Response.Expires = -1` resolved the issue.  For some reason this was preventing the image from working properly in IE.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you have to fix the file type association on the client for this to work. Known issue - Windows Updates often breaks this association resulting in this type of error message.

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/36147698/office-updates-break-tiff-file-associations.aspx

**UPDATE**

1.) Create a blank text document on your desktop. (File.txt)

2.) Change the file extension from .txt to .tiff.

3.) Right click on the .tiff file and select open.  On the next box choose “select program from a list of installed programs.

4.) Click on the browse button and browse to “C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MODI\12.0”.

5.) Select “MSPVIEW.EXE” and click “Open”.

6.) Select “Microsoft Office Document Imaging” and click OK.

7.) You will get a message saying it is unable to open the document.  That is because it is not an actual graphic image.  We are just setting the file association at this point.

8.) Repeat steps 1 – 7 and use .tif as apposed to .tiff because there are two different file extensions for this type of document.

Comment: An annoying issue, but I'm not getting the file at all, I just get an error that it can't download Default.aspx.